# How do I send URLs from current page to destination page?

Tags: jquery

On page one, I have a div container that looks like this in HTML:

```
<div class="wpcm-vehicle-results-wrapper">
        <ul class="wpcm-vehicle-results"><li class="wpcm-listings-item wpcm-listings-item-featured">
<a href="https://www.sr19repairables.com/vehicles/rebuilt-vehicles/2016-chevrolet-silverado-3500-hd-crew-cab-high-country-pickup-4d-6-1-2-ft-bed/" title="2016 Chevrolet Silverado 3500 HD Crew Cab High Country Pickup 4D 6 1/2 ft Bed">
            <div class="wpcm-listings-item-image-wrapper">
                    <img src="https://i0.wp.com/www.sr19repairables.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/2016-Chevy-Silverado-1.jpg?resize=100%2C100&amp;ssl=1" class="wpcm-listings-item-image wp-post-image" alt="2016 Chevrolet Silverado 3500 HD Crew Cab High Country Pickup 4D 6 1/2 ft Bed" title="2016 Chevrolet Silverado 3500 HD Crew Cab High Country Pickup 4D 6 1/2 ft Bed" srcset="https://i0.wp.com/www.sr19repairables.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/2016-Chevy-Silverado-1.jpg?resize=150%2C150&amp;ssl=1 150w, https://i0.wp.com/www.sr19repairables.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/2016-Chevy-Silverado-1.jpg?resize=1024%2C1024&amp;ssl=1 1024w, https://i0.wp.com/www.sr19repairables.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/2016-Chevy-Silverado-1.jpg?resize=100%2C100&amp;ssl=1 100w, https://i0.wp.com/www.sr19repairables.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/2016-Chevy-Silverado-1.jpg?zoom=2&amp;resize=100%2C100&amp;ssl=1 200w, https://i0.wp.com/www.sr19repairables.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/2016-Chevy-Silverado-1.jpg?zoom=3&amp;resize=100%2C100&amp;ssl=1 300w" sizes="(max-width: 100px) 100vw, 100px" width="100" height="100">                  </div>
    <div class="wpcm-listings-item-description">
                    <h3>2016 Chevrolet Silverado 3500 HD Crew Cab High Country Pickup 4D 6 1/2 ft Bed</h3>
        <p>Heated and cooled seats, brown leather...and just about everything else</p>
                </div>
    <div class="wpcm-listings-item-meta">
                    <ul>
            <li class="wpcm-title">2016 Chevrolet Silverado 3500 HD Crew Cab High Country Pickup 4D 6 1/2 ft Bed</li>
            <li class="wpcm-price"><span class="amount">$44,500</span></li>
            <li>59,000 miles</li>
            <li>2016</li>
        </ul>
                </div>
        </a>
</li><li class="wpcm-listings-item wpcm-listings-item-featured">
<a href="https://www.sr19repairables.com/vehicles/rebuilt-vehicles/2015-chevrolet-malibu-lt-sedan-4d/" title="2015 Chevrolet Malibu LT Sedan 4D">
            <div class="wpcm-listings-item-image-wrapper">
                    <img src="https://i2.wp.com/www.sr19repairables.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/2015-Chevy-Malibu-1.jpg?resize=100%2C100&amp;ssl=1" class="wpcm-listings-item-image wp-post-image" alt="2015 Chevrolet Malibu LT Sedan 4D" title="2015 Chevrolet Malibu LT Sedan 4D" srcset="https://i2.wp.com/www.sr19repairables.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/2015-Chevy-Malibu-1.jpg?resize=150%2C150&amp;ssl=1 150w, https://i2.wp.com/www.sr19repairables.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/2015-Chevy-Malibu-1.jpg?resize=1024%2C1024&amp;ssl=1 1024w, https://i2.wp.com/www.sr19repairables.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/2015-Chevy-Malibu-1.jpg?resize=100%2C100&amp;ssl=1 100w, https://i2.wp.com/www.sr19repairables.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/2015-Chevy-Malibu-1.jpg?zoom=2&amp;resize=100%2C100&amp;ssl=1 200w, https://i2.wp.com/www.sr19repairables.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/2015-Chevy-Malibu-1.jpg?zoom=3&amp;resize=100%2C100&amp;ssl=1 300w" sizes="(max-width: 100px) 100vw, 100px" width="100" height="100">                    </div>
    <div class="wpcm-listings-item-description">
                    <h3>2015 Chevrolet Malibu LT Sedan 4D</h3>
        <p>Great Malibu, sharp look with tinted windows, don't miss out!</p>
                </div>
    <div class="wpcm-listings-item-meta">
                    <ul>
            <li class="wpcm-title">2015 Chevrolet Malibu LT Sedan 4D</li>
            <li class="wpcm-price"><span class="amount">$6,495</span></li>
            <li>50,800 miles</li>
            <li>2015</li>
        </ul>
                </div>
        </a>
```

When I click on one of the URLs in the `<a href>` elements, I need to send the URLs from all of the `<a href>` elements along and put them in an array on the page I'm going to. Is there any way to do this? Thanks for your help.

Update: Here's what I've tried so far: I took the info Barmar so kindly gave me and wrote these two `.js` files:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
url_array = $("a[href]").map((i, a) => a.href).get();
localStorage.setItem("urls", "url_array");
});
```

and

```
document.getElementById("posts").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("urls");
```

I called the first file on my first page and then the second file on my second page where I have a `<div>` with an id of `posts` and it's not bringing anything up. I really don't know that much about coding, I use wordpress to build my site and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the URLs all in the same domain as your page? You could put the array of URLs into `sessionStorage`.

Comment: `url_array = $("a[href]").map((i, a) => a.href).get()`

Comment: Where do I use that code?

Comment: Unless the URLs change dynamically, you can put it in `$(document).ready()` and get all the URLs when the page is loaded. Then you can use `localStorage.setItem()` to add it to local storage, and the next page can read it with `localStorage.getItem()`.

Comment: I hope you're not expecting us to write the code for you. I'm just pointing you in the right direction, you're the programmer.

Comment: OK, one more question: I'm using the `localStorage.setItem()` on three different pages. If I set it on the first page, then go to the second page and set a different array of URLs, will it overwrite the first array or create a second?

Comment: Local storage is by domain. If you set the same name on a different page in the same domain, it will overwrite it.